# Is there a 'Answer in progress' state? Or should there be one?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, fastest-gun

I am using SO frequently, more as user than contributing, but I see comments like "we just gave the same answer within minutes" very often.

Would it not be very useful, if there was a state "n Answers in progress" if someone starts to answer. like "question viewed n times"?

It would help the nice and good people answering easy questions, not to waste time giving the (almost) same answer within a minute or two.

Comment: It might have the opposite effect: "Oh $#!+, someone is already writing an answer. I need to do mine faster so I can be the first!"

Comment: This has been proposed before at least once, with discussion; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/user-x-is-writing-an-answer-banner-to-appear-when-another-user-is-writing-to

Comment: Simply because there is an "answer in progress" doesn't mean it's a good answer, the correct answer, the best answer, or that it will ever be posted at all (the poster could cancel before submitting, or get caught up in a phone call or work related task and leave the answer pending for hours).

Answer (score 14):

This would actually be really fun to play with. You could design an algorithm to pick one person to *not* show the message to, and thus encourage some folks to answer and others to not. Or possibly, as Mysticial notes, encourage more "placeholder" answers.

...but there's a simpler, less creepy/manipulative solution that doesn't require any changes at all:

1. Either skip trivial questions and answer stuff that takes a bit more effort, or...
2. Get really really fast at writing, and if you're *still* too slow then just delete your answer. Worst-case, you've only wasted a minute or so.

Note that if someone actually *posts* an answer while you're typing yours, you will be notified of that and provided with the means of loading it in place. At this point, you can decide whether or not to keep writing.

#### See also:

- ["User X is writing an answer" - banner to appear when another user is writing too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/user-x-is-writing-an-answer-banner-to-appear-when-another-user-is-writing-to)
- [Ability to see active participants currently adding new answer to a question by inspecting saved drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166871/ability-to-see-active-participants-currently-adding-new-answer-to-a-question-by)
- [When answering, could we be informed that "the following people are already answering this question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/when-answering-could-we-be-informed-that-the-following-people-are-already-answ)