# Show my answer to others as I'm writing it

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have no expectation of this happening because it's too difficult technically, but it would be cool if (there was an option to) as I'm writing an answer, display it in real time to other users (just as I can see a preview of the text as I'm writing an answer).

I want this because when answering a new question, I feel like I'm rushing to post *something* just so someone else doesn't post the same answer sooner, which would mean I've wasted my time since there's no point in posting what I've been writing anymore. This causes me to write something fast and short and then add details in edits. You can see it on old questions too where people have given the same answer within minutes of each other, which wouldn't happen if they could see someone else was already writing what they wanted to write.

Comment: *"which wouldn't happen if they could see someone else was already writing what they wanted to write"* - what makes you think it wouldn't happen anyway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a 'Answer in progress' state? Or should there be one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259985/is-there-a-answer-in-progress-state-or-should-there-be-one)

Comment: [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)

Comment: @JeanneDark sort of but not exactly.

Comment: *The flower is writing an answer ... &^&^%$ Makoto ...*

Comment: @rene answer progress `[          ]`

Comment: @VLAZ but I want to see *exactly* what the flower has written so far, in real-time, typos and all, not a progress bar.

Comment: @rene presumably if you saw Makoto was already writing an answer and it was looking similar to what you wanted to say, you wouldn't waste your time starting to write one, right? If so, I appreciate you demonstrating exactly the situation that would be prevented by my feature request.

Comment: I think this may actually increase accusations of plagiarism. "So-and-so clearly copy/pasted my in progress answer and then posted it before I could finish adding details!"

Comment: @BSMP I am only interested in having correct answers to questions, I do not care about who wrote them or how they got there at all. Just like on Wikipedia.

Comment: Rest assured I have something much better to say then Makoto but I often prefer not to do so ....

Comment: @rene:  No please, go ahead and say it. :D  I just figured I'd get the answer in as opposed to try to machinate in the comments.

Comment: For me, it's not a competition. I am here to contribute and not to race against each other. The whole premise of this question is, if i can't be the first, then I should leave because most probably, their answers will get accepted. This is not a positive Outlook and initiates unhealthy atmosphere. Moreover, until I post submit, I haven't agreed to publish my answer in SO. Why should others see my answer when I myself haven't given the node to show?

Comment: You state that your are *"[...] only interested in having correct answers to questions [...]"* and *"[...] do not care about who wrote them [...]"* If that's the case, why not just bookmark the question, wait for a couple of hours, and see if it still needs answering, instead of *"[...] rushing to post something just so someone else doesn't post the same answer sooner"*?

Comment: Oh no, now we'll have to deal with answerers-exhibitionists! In all seriousness, the proposal can actually backfire and prevent potentially good answers from being posted because the would-be answerer will see what others are writing and decide it is not worth it, never to know that once they start working on a problem, they may come up with a different solution, word the answer better, give a unique example, etc. Not to mention issues others mentioned like plagiarism (take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406006/11407695) and imagine the issue with the proposal implemented).

Comment: do I get a badge if I get enough downvotes?

Comment: @Boris nope, but you can take solace in that yours is far from [the most disagreed-with proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405582/is-downvoting-harmful-and-should-it-be-removed-completely) (as of 2021) :)

Comment: @OlegValter that's a shame, I was hoping for a record

Comment: *...I do not care about who wrote them...* @Boris I meant that other users are likely to do this. I did not mean to imply that it would be you complaining. But we have had users complain of plagiarism when it comes to answers posted within minutes of their own.

Answer (score 27):

Don't rush, and try to minimize the pressures you get from others writing answers to a question.

The point of answering the question is to **answer the question**.  There will always be a [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368), but your objective is to just **answer the question** as succinctly and as expertly as you can.

(Note that five or six people rushing to answer a question may be a smell of something else going on with the question, but that varies from topic to topic.)

Comment: My post is a suggestion for how to fix that issue then, there's no point in copying an answer if you can already see someone is going to answer the way you want to. You could just wait and edit the answer to be more correct if you find something missing.

Comment: @Boris if the only way an answer to be relevant is to be posted first, then it hints at the question not being good. A *good* question should be answerable by multiple people and should take more than 5 minutes, usually.

Comment: @Boris:  Like I said, that's a smell.  If six people could answer the question in 30 seconds or less, there's a *very* good chance that there's a duplicate floating around somewhere.

Comment: @Boris - The same answer can contained the same quoted text, but the individual answers, contain (or should contain) more than just text that is copied from another source.  I don't find answers that are just a copy and paste from another source to be very helpful, and almost always, downvote low quality answers like that. Why you feel the need to rush, writing an answer, is still not clear.

Comment: Furthermore, oftentimes while I'm writing my answer someone else posts an answer with little to no details, then once I post my answer that does have details, it either gets more upvotes or is accepted.

Answer (score 7):

There's no harm in having a couple of similar answers saying substantially the same thing, especially if they say it in slightly different ways. If two people's answers agree, there's a good chance that they're both correct, so they reinforce each other's credibility. This is good for the OP, and for future visitors.

If you submit an answer and then notice that it's a near dupe of an existing answer, and you feel that your answer adds no value, and is just cluttering the page, then consider deleting it. Remember, mods & members with 10k+ rep can see deleted answers. To some of us, you gain a measure of respect for deleting such answers, and IMHO that kind of respect is more valuable than rep points.

It might feel like you've wasted time and energy by writing an answer that you delete a few minutes after you submit it. But I believe that writing a good answer is it's own reward. Each answer that you write improves your answer writing skills. And it's often the case that we learn new things, or refresh things we might be a little rusty on, when writing a good answer. I've certainly improved my knowledge of the official Python documentation by writing lots of Python answers on SO. ;)